# return a generic string list from Handler to a JS array

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, arrays

Trying to return this list as an array so I can then grab it on the client side via JS and iterate through its values.

So one of my .ashx methods returns a list like this in the end of the method:

equipmentTypes is a generic list of strings

```
        _httpContext.Response.ContentType = "text";
        _httpContext.Response.Write(equipmentTypes.ToArray());
```

When i receive it on the client, I get the literal text "System.String[]".  So what content type should I return?  Obviously this is not correct.

Then I assume I can eval this into an array (object) on the js side.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) when sending data to javascript.  You SHOULD NOT use eval as this opens you up to many security vulnerabilities (i.e. [XSS](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/gmurray71/archive/2006/09/preventing_cros.html)).

See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx) for more on C# and JSON, including turning a C# array into JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You should serialize the objects that you wish to write to the response stream as JSON, the content-type of which is `application/json`. You could either use the built-in [DataContract serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) or a third-party open source library such as the [NewtonSoft](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) JSON.Net library.

On the client you should use `JSON.parse` rather than `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you can generate JSON using the built-in [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
_httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
_httpContext.Response.Write(js.Serialize(equipmentTypes.ToArray()));
```

And on the client you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (supported by all modern browsers) to get an array back. `eval` is not really a security risk when you are in control of both client and server, but it's still the wrong tool for the job.